# 辞書内包表記で返す値を関数から取得したい

Tags: python, python3

辞書内包表記で記載すると可読性が高いと思い、その方法を探しています。
代案としては下記に記載した通り、関数でTupleを返しdict()を使用する事で実現ができております。

正直、「辞書の内包表記はPythonの構文で定義されているため、関数で返すという事はできない。」という結論になるのではないかと思っております。
もしそうであれば、その旨回答して頂けると助かります
※ドキュメントなどは見つからなかったので提示して頂けると更に嬉しいです
※代案についても他にやり方があれば是非教えてください

詳細は下記に記載します

### やりたい事

このようなforで書いたコードを

```py
l = ['a', 'b']
def f(s):
  # 実際にはそれなりにコストがかかる処理でKeyとValueを作成する
  k = s * 2
  v = s * 3
  return k, v
d = {}
for s in l:
  k, v = f(s)
  d[k] = v
print(d) # {'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb'}
```

以下のようなイメージで内包表記で書きたい

```py
l = ['a', 'b']
def f(s):
  # 実際にはそれなりにコストがかかる処理でKeyとValueを作成する
  k = s * 2
  v = s * 3
  # ※ここでどのように返せばよいかを知りたい
  return k:v # イメージです。（構文エラーになります）

d = {f(s) for s in l}
print(d) # {'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb'}
```

※Keyの重複に対する考慮は不要です。

### 代案

一旦リスト内包表記でList[Tuple]とした上で、dictに変換する

```py
l = ['a', 'b']
def f(s):
  # 実際にはそれなりにコストがかかる処理でKeyとValueを作成する
  k = s * 2
  v = s * 3
  return k, v

d = dict([f(s) for s in l])
print(d) # {'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb'}
```

Comment: 「代案に書いてあるコードが正着」に見えるので、何を問題にしているのかピンとこないですね…

Comment: わかりづらく申し訳ありません。辞書の内包表記で「{s*2:s*3 for s in l}」とある時に、「s*2:s*3」の部分を関数から取得したいというのが質問になります。ただ、それだけだと、こうすればできるという案が回答として付きそうだったので、予め代案を書いておいた次第です。

Comment: 私が書いたのは「代案に書いてあるコードがPython的に一番素直に見える」ということで、「けっきょく質問の意味は?」となってます。

Comment: 「代案に書いてあるコードがPython的に一番素直に見える」というのが、私が欲しかった回答になります。わかりづらい質問で申し訳ありません。代案以外に満たす方法はないですか？という質問で、「ないです。」というのがquickquipさんの回答という認識です。回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: その認識は問題ないです。ただわたしがコメントした理由は、「必要性」がなければ「こういう書き方はあるのでしょうか?」という質問をする理由はないはずですが、その点が何も書かれていないからです。そのせいで質問が何を問題にしているのかピンとこないものになっています、という指摘です。そのあたりを追記してもらえるといいのですが（ここはそういう欄だと思っています）。

Comment: 質問に追記してみましたがどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f(s)` の戻り値をタプルにした上でジェネレーター式にすれば高速に書けそうです。

```
d = dict(f(s) for s in l)
```

これならリストへの変換もはさみません。

追記：
今こんな感じで比較してみたんですけどあんまり差ないですね……。

```
>>> def f(x, n):
...   y = [x for x in 'xyzw' * 100]
...   return (x+str(n), x+random.choice(y))
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('x = dict([f(x, n) for n, x in enumerate(\'abcdef\'*10000)])', globals=locals(),number=100)
41.55919947102666
>>> timeit.timeit('x = dict(f(x, n) for n, x in enumerate(\'abcdef\'*10000))', globals=locals(),number=100)
40.46618250303436
>>>
```

リスト内包が最適化されてるのと、`dict` が組み込み関数なので処理が特別なのかもしれません。なのであんま気にしなくてよいのかも。

Answer (score 1):

`f()` 関数の戻り値を dict 型のインスタンスにして [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) を使います。

```py
from functools import reduce

def f(s):
  k = s * 2
  v = s * 3
  return {k: v}

l = ['a', 'b']
d = reduce(lambda d1, d2: (d1.update(d2) or d1), map(f, l), {})
print(d)
=>
{'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb'}
```